# AJAX - respond differently depending on server response

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

Here is my C# code:

```
   if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(bookRoom))
        {
              ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP1); //If we ever upgrade, its not that important but change this to the right version



        //service.UseDefaultCredentials = true;


        service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("MYNLJ", "", "");
        service.Url = new Uri("http://DIR/EWS/Exchange.asmx"); //This is the EWS file

        Appointment appointment = new Appointment(service);



        String ITMtgMailboxToAccess = roomEmail; //Mailbox name
        FolderId ITMtgCalendarFolderId = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, ITMtgMailboxToAccess);


        appointment.Subject = "Walk In Meeting";
        appointment.Body = "Test Meeting";



        double htoAdd = Convert.ToDouble(MeetingLength.SelectedItem.Value);


        appointment.Start = DateTime.Now;
        appointment.End = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(htoAdd);
        CalendarView Checkcv = new CalendarView(appointment.Start, appointment.End); //Don't change this

        try
        {
            FindItemsResults<Appointment> ITMtgfapts = service.FindAppointments(ITMtgCalendarFolderId, Checkcv);

            List<Appointment> ITMtgappointments = new List<Appointment>();
            if (ITMtgfapts.Items.Count > 0) // If there is more than one item
            {
```

Here I want to let the ajax request know that the booking wasn't successful

```
   // "Your booking will conflict with another appointment";
            }


            else
            {
```

Let the ajax request know it was successful

```
                        //Success
                       appointment.RequiredAttendees.Add(roomEmail);



                appointment.Save(SendInvitationsMode.SendToAllAndSaveCopy);


            }
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }
```

AJAX code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(function () {
          $('#BookButton').click(function (event) {
              var form = $('#Form1');
              $.ajax({
                  type: form.attr('method'),
                  url: form.attr('action'),
                  data: $("#BookRoom :input").serialize()
              }).done(function () {
                  // Optionally alert the user of success here...
                  $('#BookRoom').modal('hide');
                  $('#SuccessMsg').text('Meeting Booked');
                  $('#SuccessMessage').modal('show');
                  setTimeout(function () { $('#SuccessMessage').modal('hide'); }, 3000);
              }).fail(function () {
                  // Optionally alert the user of an error here...
                  alert("Error submitting AJAX request");
              });
              event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the form from submitting via the browser.
          });
      });
```

Comment: Eh...? So what is your question? I don't really fancy trawling through your code to try and come up with a question to be honest!

Comment: @Belogix The question is how do I send responses from C# back to AJAX basically.

Answer (score 1):

My advice is to respond an enum-value. The advantage is the scalability:

C#

```
public enum ReponseType : int 
{
  Success: 0,
  InvalidInput: 1,
  ServerError: 2,
  ....
}
```

Javascript

```
var ResponseType = {
  Success: 0,
  InvalidInput: 1,
  ServerError: 2,
  ....
}
```

On the server:

```
return base.Json(ReponseType.Success);
// or return base.Json(ReponseType.InvalidInput);
// or return base.Json(ReponseType.ServerError);
```

On the client:

```
$.ajax({
  ...
}).done(function (data) {
  if (data === ResponseType.Success) {
    // Notify user: Success
  }
  else if (data === ResponseType.InvalidInput) {
    // Notify user: It is his fault
  }
  else if (data === ResponseType.ServerError) {
    // Notify user: It is your fault
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, will give this a go now and let you know how I get on :)

Comment: Vanillebar Lutz The C# code is producing an error: Expected }

Comment: Where is this error located ? Can you serve me a bigger snippet through pastebin?

Comment: pastebin.com/pu2vYAtw

Comment: Think I've fixed that error, now getting System.Web.UI.Page does not contain a definition for json

Comment: Ouh ... Sorry ... I thought you were using ASP.NET MVC, but it seems you are using ASP.NET WebForms. I am not experienced in working with WebForms. I am afraid I can't help you anymore :( I am very sorry. Maybe you can adapt some of my approaches.